# Add second uploaded image on display

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, position

as you can see on this website (its just a testing website) you can upload a picture and it wil be showen on the left uper box. But now i need to add a second picture under it.

Comment: we cannot see anything ...

Comment: sorry this is the website http://jordan-it.nl/achraf/Logotest.php

Comment: you are replacing the image src try changing script in js file.

Comment: How do i do that. i am not really fimiliar with javascript